# Python Django Forms

Tags: python, html, django, forms, python-3.5

I'm quite new for the web development using Python.
I am using the following example (given in some of the questions in this website) python and HTML files in order to create a django form with Python 3.5.2:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
'',
url(r'^email/$',
    views.email,
    name='email'
    ),
url(r'^thanks/$',
    views.thanks,
    name='thanks'
    ),)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from yourapp.forms import ContactForm


def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('thanks')
    return render(request, "yourapp/email.html", {'form': form})


def thanks(request):
    return HttpResponse('Thank you for your message.')
```

**email.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

However, everytime I run the html file I can't get the form on the page. Instead I get the following screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWj7V.jpg)

What can be the problem?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is not a question about forms, but a basic misunderstanding of how to use Django. You should go and do the introductory Django tutorial.

Comment: I second this. The Django tutorial is very good and will give you a much better idea of how Django works.

Comment: I was rushing for a project so I should've missed something.. I'll go through the tutorials again. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run the HTML file on its own. You need to run the Django development server using this command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

You should then be able to see the form at http://localhost:8000/email/

Answer (score 0):

The very first Django tutorial mentions that to test your application you need to start the development server through the following command:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

Check this for more details [The development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server)